# I need to create multiple ImageViews in a ViewFlipper dynamically for a slideshow App

Tags: java, android, xml, slideshow, viewflipper

So I try to make an application which gets some images from a certain path and creates an animation out of them, I am stuck at the part where the user has to state the amount of pictures and create the ImagesViews dynamically by code... Help please !!!

The important part of my MainActivity.java

```
//Internet Images

    int counter=0;


    temp_viewer = String.valueOf(counter);
    Log.v("Value of counter", temp_viewer);
    Log.v("Value of path_url", path_url);

    ImageView internet_00 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView0);
    Picasso.with(this).load(path_url + "0" + counter + ".jpg").into(internet_00);

    counter = counter +1;

    temp_viewer = String.valueOf(counter);
    Log.v("Value of counter", temp_viewer);
    Log.v("Value of path_url", path_url);

    ImageView internet_01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
    Picasso.with(this).load(path_url + "0" + counter + ".jpg").into(internet_01);


    //Slideshow

    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.backgroundViewFlipper1);

    fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_in);

    fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_out);
    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(fade_in);
    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(fade_out);

    //Sets Auto Flipping

    viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
    viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(5000);
    viewFlipper.startFlipping();
```

My XML file (important part only)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout">

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/backgroundViewFlipper1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView0"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           />

    </ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hello, my friend I have the same problem :(